# Will there be any issues with my countdown timer?

Tags: javascript

This code for a countdown timer is taken from W3Schools:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

var countDownDate = new Date("May 2, 2018 15:54:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now - n;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }

}, 1000);
```

There was a big issue with it: any date I enter would not work for different timezones, as if it was +1 hour UTC it would expire, and it would be an hour long if it was -1.

So I added the `d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;` to get the milliseconds difference, and then took it off, so if there is any difference it should calculate it.

Will it always work if I put an UTC date in the future, or is there a possible difference I don't know about (for example a special country or daylight savings that could mess it up)?

Comment: @KevinBoucher According to the question, the code came from w3schools. For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect OP, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is. Please take a look at [Code Review's help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That is not the issue though, I am just wanting to know about the timezone offset and any possible quirks it may have (Not a review of the code)

Comment: @ochi You didn't read the comment above yours? OP is explicitly not looking for a review. It may be off-topic for Stack Overflow, that doesn't mean it's on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @everyone From all my testing, everything seems to work with many different timezones on my local system (As long as the date is a UTC date), but if there were say daylight savings would this mess anything up?